# Mathematica kernel dies

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, kernel

When I run the following code, the kernel dies. I have tried making a new kernel, but that also does not work. The memory usage never crosses 33% of the total RAM available. I have no clue how to fix this. Please help. I am running it on the default local kernel now. I am using Mathematica 12.3

```
SimpIntegrate\[Theta]1 = {{1/(
 8 Ep Eq (m + Ep Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cp p Sinh[\[Zeta]]) (m + 
    Eq Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cq q Sinh[\[Zeta]])) Sqrt[1 - cp^2] Sqrt[
 1 - cq^2]
  E^(-((Ep^2 + Eq^2 - 2 m^2)/(
  2 \[Sigma]^2))) (Ep - m) (Eq - 
   m) \[Pi]^2 ((Eq + m)^2 (3 (Ep + m)^2 - cp^2 p^2) - 
   4 cp cq (Ep + m) (Eq + m) p q - (cq^2 (Ep + m)^2 + 
      3 (-1 + cq^2 + cp^2 (1 - 2 cq^2)) p^2) q^2 + 
   4 ((Ep + m)^2 (Eq + m)^2 + (-1 + cq^2 + 
         cp^2 (1 - 2 cq^2)) p^2 q^2) Cosh[\[Zeta]] + ((Eq + 
         m)^2 ((Ep + m)^2 + cp^2 p^2) + 
      4 cp cq (Ep + m) (Eq + 
         m) p q + (cq^2 (Ep + m)^2 + (1 - cq^2 + 
            cp^2 (-1 + 2 cq^2)) p^2) q^2) Cosh[2 \[Zeta]] + 
   4 (cp (Eq + m) p + cq (Ep + m) q) ((Ep + m) (Eq + m) - 
      cp cq p q + ((Ep + m) (Eq + m) + 
         cp cq p q) Cosh[\[Zeta]]) Sinh[\[Zeta]]), 0, 0, (
Sqrt[1 - cp^2] Sqrt[1 - cq^2]
  E^(-((Ep^2 + Eq^2 - 2 m^2)/(
  2 \[Sigma]^2))) (Ep - m) (Eq - 
   m) \[Pi]^2 ((Ep + m) Cosh[\[Zeta]/2] + 
   cp p Sinh[\[Zeta]/2])^2 ((Eq + m) Cosh[\[Zeta]/2] + 
   cq q Sinh[\[Zeta]/2])^2)/(
Ep Eq (m + Ep Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cp p Sinh[\[Zeta]]) (m + 
   Eq Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cq q Sinh[\[Zeta]]))}, {0, 
1/(2 Ep Eq (m + Ep Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cp p Sinh[\[Zeta]]) (m + 
    Eq Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cq q Sinh[\[Zeta]]))
  Sqrt[1 - cp^2] Sqrt[1 - cq^2]
   E^(-((Ep^2 + Eq^2 - 2 m^2)/(
   2 \[Sigma]^2))) (Ep - m) (-Eq + m) \[Pi]^2 Sinh[\[Zeta]/
   2]^2 ((-1 + cp^2) (Eq + 
       m)^2 p^2 + ((-1 + cq^2) (Ep + m)^2 + (cp^2 + cq^2 - 
          2 cp^2 cq^2) p^2) q^2 + ((-1 + cp^2) (Eq + 
          m)^2 p^2 + ((-1 + cq^2) (Ep + m)^2 + (-cq^2 + 
             cp^2 (-1 + 2 cq^2)) p^2) q^2) Cosh[\[Zeta]] + 
    2 p q ((-1 + cp^2) cq (Eq + m) p + 
       cp (-1 + cq^2) (Ep + m) q) Sinh[\[Zeta]]), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
1/(2 Ep Eq (m + Ep Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cp p Sinh[\[Zeta]]) (m + 
    Eq Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cq q Sinh[\[Zeta]]))
  Sqrt[1 - cp^2] Sqrt[1 - cq^2]
   E^(-((Ep^2 + Eq^2 - 2 m^2)/(
   2 \[Sigma]^2))) (Ep - m) (-Eq + m) \[Pi]^2 Sinh[\[Zeta]/
   2]^2 ((-1 + cp^2) (Eq + 
       m)^2 p^2 + ((-1 + cq^2) (Ep + m)^2 + (cp^2 + cq^2 - 
          2 cp^2 cq^2) p^2) q^2 + ((-1 + cp^2) (Eq + 
          m)^2 p^2 + ((-1 + cq^2) (Ep + m)^2 + (-cq^2 + 
             cp^2 (-1 + 2 cq^2)) p^2) q^2) Cosh[\[Zeta]] + 
    2 p q ((-1 + cp^2) cq (Eq + m) p + 
       cp (-1 + cq^2) (Ep + m) q) Sinh[\[Zeta]]), 0}, {(
Sqrt[1 - cp^2] Sqrt[1 - cq^2]
  E^(-((Ep^2 + Eq^2 - 2 m^2)/(
  2 \[Sigma]^2))) (Ep - m) (Eq - 
   m) \[Pi]^2 ((Ep + m) Cosh[\[Zeta]/2] + 
   cp p Sinh[\[Zeta]/2])^2 ((Eq + m) Cosh[\[Zeta]/2] + 
   cq q Sinh[\[Zeta]/2])^2)/(
Ep Eq (m + Ep Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cp p Sinh[\[Zeta]]) (m + 
   Eq Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cq q Sinh[\[Zeta]])), 0, 0, 
1/(8 Ep Eq (m + Ep Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cp p Sinh[\[Zeta]]) (m + 
    Eq Cosh[\[Zeta]] + cq q Sinh[\[Zeta]])) Sqrt[1 - cp^2] Sqrt[
 1 - cq^2]
  E^(-((Ep^2 + Eq^2 - 2 m^2)/(
  2 \[Sigma]^2))) (Ep - m) (Eq - 
   m) \[Pi]^2 ((Eq + m)^2 (3 (Ep + m)^2 - cp^2 p^2) - 
   4 cp cq (Ep + m) (Eq + m) p q - (cq^2 (Ep + m)^2 + 
      3 (-1 + cq^2 + cp^2 (1 - 2 cq^2)) p^2) q^2 + 
   4 ((Ep + m)^2 (Eq + m)^2 + (-1 + cq^2 + 
         cp^2 (1 - 2 cq^2)) p^2 q^2) Cosh[\[Zeta]] + ((Eq + 
         m)^2 ((Ep + m)^2 + cp^2 p^2) + 
      4 cp cq (Ep + m) (Eq + 
         m) p q + (cq^2 (Ep + m)^2 + (1 - cq^2 + 
            cp^2 (-1 + 2 cq^2)) p^2) q^2) Cosh[2 \[Zeta]] + 
   4 (cp (Eq + m) p + cq (Ep + m) q) ((Ep + m) (Eq + m) - 
      cp cq p q + ((Ep + m) (Eq + m) + 
         cp cq p q) Cosh[\[Zeta]]) Sinh[\[Zeta]])}};
Integrate\[Phi] =  Integrate[SimpIntegrate\[Theta]1, {cp, 1, -1}, {cq, 1, -1}]
```

I think if I put a semi-colon at the end of the last line, it fixes the issue. I don't understand the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Running on Windows 11 / 64 Bit Architecture using MMA Ver. 13.3.1
I get an answer in 1294.94 seconds without the system hanging:

CPU usage: varies from about 5.2-20.1% on Intel i9 System with 128 GB
Memory Usage: about 6912 MB max
With a solution of 3.2 MB

I have no idea of how to tell if the solution is correct, nor do I know how to post the output here.  It is very large and quite formidable.

Comment: Can you share it somehow

Comment: Is there a way to pass large output on this site?  I went into a private chat once with another user in response to a question i have, but I don't know how to initiate one.  Perhaps another user can provide guidance.  That might be the best way to address this.

Comment: New to Dropbox so I don't know if I got the link set to the correct access to allow you to view it, but I've shared the notebook with answer here:  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/durzt991ye5umuuywyiye/MSE293850.nb?rlkey=hli445nrurosgjajy3kh8ytsb&dl=0

Comment: It works thank you

Answer (score 2):

It takes about one hour and slightly over 10 gigs memory, and it finishes. No crash. I did not used ; at the end of lines. Wolfram Engine 13.3.0 Linux version and Ryzen 5900X cpu.